# How to generate the tfdf of a large corpus using multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to generate the term-frequency and doc-frequence for a large corpus. There are libraries doing that, but they are not as flexible as I want. This is what I'm currently doing, but with only one process. How can I speed up this exercise by using multiprocessing? Thank you!

```
#txtfiles is a list of file paths

def get_tf_df(txtfiles, tf_dict, df_dict):

    for txtfile in txtfiles:
        tokens = get_tokens(txtfile)
        for t in tokens:
            update tf_dict (I know this part) 
            update df_dict (I know this part) 

    return tf_dict, df_dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [pool](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) of worker processes and a `Manager` instance to manage access to `tf_dict` and `df_dict` dictionaries which are shared between workers:

```
import glob
import multiprocessing as mp

from utils import get_tokens, update_tf, update_df, save_dicts

WORKERS = 4

def update_dicts(filename, tf_dict, df_dict):
    tokens = get_tokens(filename)

    for tok in tokens:
        update_tf(tok, tf_dict)
        update_df(tok, df_dict)

def main():
    manager = mp.Manager()

    tf_dict = manager.dict()
    df_dict = manager.dict()

    pool = mp.Pool(WORKERS)

    for filename in glob.glob('/path/to/texts/*.txt'):
        pool.apply_async(update_dicts, args=(filename, tf_dict, df_dict))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    save_dicts(tf_dict, df_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```